# How to decide accuracy metric for Machine Learning Model?

Tags: machine-learning

I am making a deep learning ML model in keras.
My task is to rate a person with a score from `1-10` in `3` different categories (i.e. output has to be `3` scores each from `1-10` for a given person) based on different attributes of the person like height, weight, sports etc. For the training set I have been given some people with their attributes and labels as the `3` scores.
In my model I used one hot vector encoding for the output. i.e. I made `3x10=30` output neurons where each neuron indicates a particular category and score respectively (I am using the `categorical_crossentropy` loss function and hence I get 1 or 0 as output in each neuron from which I convert it back to see the predicted scores).
My problem is that I am not able to understand what accuracy metric should I use in this case. I need the same trend as the actual scores. Any suggestions for the metric(can also be a self-defined metric).

Example of output:

```
Category A score: 5
Category B score: 3
Category C score: 7

Output Vector: 00001 00000 00100 00000 00000 01000
```

(Spaces above in vector are just for ease of readability)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a weighted sum of the three categories loss functions. Given that for category `i`,  `i \in {1, 2, 3}`, the loss is `l_i` then the metric can be `\alpha_1 * l_1 + \alpha_2 * l_2 + \alpha_3 * l_3`, where `\alpha_i` is the weight for category `i` and you can adjust it given the importance of the category. And for the loss, you have many options. This is because, as stated in keras documentation [here](https://keras.io/metrics/), "You may use any of the loss functions as a metric function.".

However, there is one issue, when you have a scoring system (like your problem that have scores from 1 to 9), then if the label is 9 and your model is predicting 8, it is better than your model predicting 1. But, it looks this is not grasped the way you model your system. Hence you may use `categorical_crossentropy` loss function with the probabilities (softmax outputs) or maybe use `mean_square_error` loss function.

Comment: what activation functions should I use when trying mean_square_error as the metric? I am taking the scores out of 10 as the outputs and no rescaling of the scores is being done.

Comment: As you have three categories, if you want to use mean_square_error loss and solve the problem as a regression problem, you need to have three neurons at the last layer, one for each category. The previous layer is connected to these these neurons (fully connected). For each of these three neurons in the last layer you may use a linear activation (as you have a regression problem) . You can read more [HERE](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-which-loss-and-activation-functions-should-i-use-ac02f1c56aa8), on what activation and loss to use.